# What is the policy for users who deliberately vandalise their own posts?

Tags: discussion, vandalism

I came across this post today:

[proving $L^\infty$ norm inequality (disprove $\Vert f\Vert_\infty\le\sqrt{n}$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234144/proving-l-infty-norm-inequality-disprove-vert-f-vert-infty-le-sqrtn)

The user deliberately deleted a large chunk of his/her own post, making the question unintelligible before the edit was rolled back. What is the community policy on such behaviour, especially if the user is recalcitrant, or makes new accounts to do this again and again? I believe such users might have motives that are not good (e.g. cheating and trying to cover their tracks). Should new users need community approval to edit their own posts?

Comment: An important point is that you should *never* get into an edit war. If the user reverts your rollback, just flag for mod attention but don't roll back again. Moderators have ways to deal with such situations, as a regular user you can't prevent the user from rolling back again.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you already possess editing privileges, upon seeing such self-vandalism, your first course of action could be to roll back the edit to the previous useful version, as well as leaving a (polite!) comment that such vandalism is frowned upon. If user persists on ill behavior, flag for mod attention, and leave the mods to deal with the user appropriately.