# OP defaced their question, after an answer was given.

Tags: discussion

I came across a [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369789/deleted-question_) with the question post erased by the asker. There was an answer at the time of defacement. So I rolled back to the original post. But my suggested edit was rejected. Should I not have suggested the edit?

Another question which got defaced:
[How can it be shown that D (Zariski closed subset) is irreducible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4276032/how-can-we-prove-f-is-irreducible). This question is not closed.

Comment: Did you suggest the title should be changed?  It's hard for me to tell what your rollback suggestion amounted to.

Comment: @hardmath no, i rolled back to the first revision. but i think the problem has been solved already.

Comment: second problem has been solved too.

Comment: See this list of [duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32896/list-of-duplicates-questions-defaced-or-vandalised) about the policy for users who deface (or delete) their own posts.  You did the appropriate thing (rollback to version that got a good answer), and apparently the two reviewers confused your rollback with the OP's defacement.  The only further policy note is not to engage in a rollback war if the defacement is repeated.  At that point flag for moderator attention.

Comment: 2 [rollbacks from the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222644/282094) automatically generates a flag.